# Unable to perform Profile based optimization(PBO) in gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

I am unable to optimize my code with PBO options `(-fprofile-generate & -fprofile-use)` in gcc.

I am first compiling my code like following :
`gcc -fprofile-generate test.c -o test`

After generating profile data(.gcda file), I am re-compiling my code like following:
`gcc -fprofile-use test.c -o test`

But I am not able to see any difference in the assembly code between optimized and un-optimized code. Both looks same.

Should I also use optimization flags( e.g. `-O1`, `-O2`) along with `-fprofile-generate/-fprofile-use` to generate the optimized code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if I remember correctly, PBO must be specified manually at the linkage:

```
gcc -O3 -fprofile-generate -c -MMD -MP -MF test.d -MT test.d -o test.o src/test.c
gcc -O3 -fprofile-generate -o test test.o
```

then:

```
gcc -O3 -fprofile-use -c -MMD -MP -MF test.d -MT test.d -o test.o src/test.c
gcc -O3 -fprofile-use -o test test.o
```